# Linked Server Error on SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, linked-server, sql-server-agent

I get the below error from a SQL Server Agent Job. However, if I run the query in the job manually it works fine.
Why is this? Is it just SQL Agent that requires MSDTC?
I don't believe it is permissions issues as the job runs under a service account that is in sysadmin role.

Message

> Executed as user: SERVERS\quinsql_sa. The operation could not be
>   performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server
>   "TestServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction. [SQLSTATE
>   42000] (Error 7391)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server
>   "TestServer" returned message "The transaction manager has disabled
>   its support for remote/network transactions.". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error
>   7412).  The step failed.

The involved versions are SQL Server 2008R2 and SQL Server 2012. The SQL Job is on the 2008R2

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen this exactly before, it does seem strange that you can run the query manually but not as an agent job. This is not unheard of though [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1471229-391-1.aspx) has a similar post a couple of years ago, but has some reasonably complex queries involved.

What is the query you're trying to run doing?

As Tom V said, it would be helpful to know what version of SQL Server you're both running the query *from*, and where the linked server is connecting *to*

When you run the query manually:

- Is it everything that the Agent job is doing (There isn't more than one step in the Agent job)?
- Are you using the same account as the Agent job is run as?

As a start, it's worth checking your MSDTC configuration on both servers. I don't know if it'll be that in this case but it's best to try and eliminate simple things first. Have a look at these sites to get some details on that:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767/the-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions)
[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7172223f-acbe-4472-8cdf-feec80fd2e64/the-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remotenetwork-transactions?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

Comment: The query is a stored proc , which runs a simple INSERT SELECT. That is all that the Job is doing. I had tested running the INSERT SELECT query separately and that worked. However, when I execute the Stored Procedure I get the error "The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "TestServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction"

Comment: I've had a couple of issues with this in the past. I found an answer to one such issue [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811031), and the other issue was solved by enabling the RCP settings on the linked server properties.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So the SQL Agent Job is calling a stored procedure.  That stored procedure is running the `INSERT SELECT` query.

Running the `INSERT SELECT` outside of the stored procedure worked fine.

Executing the stored procedure caused the error

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "TestServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction

To fix this I had to enable MSDTC on the server where the SQL Job/stored procedure was being called.

I'm still not quite sure why the INSERT SELECT query worked ok outside of the stored procedure.